# TypeError: community_detection() got an unexpected keyword argument 'init_max_size'

Tags: python, sentence-transformers

I'm running to an error:

> TypeError: community_detection() got an unexpected keyword argument 'init_max_size'

when I run this code

```
# keep looping through until no more clusters are created

cluster_accuracy = cluster_accuracy / 100
model = SentenceTransformer(transformer)

while cluster:

    corpus_sentences = list(corpus_set)
    check_len = len(corpus_sentences)

    corpus_embeddings = model.encode(corpus_sentences, batch_size=256, show_progress_bar=True, convert_to_tensor=True)
    clusters = util.community_detection(corpus_embeddings, min_community_size=min_cluster_size, threshold=cluster_accuracy, init_max_size=len(corpus_embeddings))

    for keyword, cluster in enumerate(clusters):
        print("\nCluster {}, #{} Elements ".format(keyword + 1, len(cluster)))

        for sentence_id in cluster[0:]:
            print("\t", corpus_sentences[sentence_id])
            corpus_sentences_list.append(corpus_sentences[sentence_id])
            cluster_name_list.append("Cluster {}, #{} Elements ".format(keyword + 1, len(cluster)))

    df_new = pd.DataFrame(None)
    df_new['Cluster Name'] = cluster_name_list
    df_new["Keyword"] = corpus_sentences_list

    df_all.append(df_new)
    have = set(df_new["Keyword"])

    corpus_set = corpus_set_all - have
    remaining = len(corpus_set)
    print("Total Unclustered Keywords: ", remaining)
    if check_len == remaining:
        break
```

this is a keyword clustering script for SEO

Answer (score 0):

On the community_detection() function, try changing the argument from `init_max_size` to `batch_size`.

see https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/util.html#sentence_transformers.util.community_detection